# calling evenReactive like a function

Tags: r, shiny

I want to take out the code doing the work in an eventReactive and put it in a wrapper function:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  numericInput("n", "n", 50),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    fun1()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
   fun2()
  })
}


fun1 = function() {
  runif(input$n)
}

fun2 = function() {
  hist(randomVals())
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However there is an error finding randomVals.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: fixed it with `randomVals <<-`, is this a good solution?

Comment: The global assignment will be applied to all current session users, they will be overwriting each other, I don't think this is what you want

Answer (score 3):

There is no reactive dependence on `renderPlot` as it has no idea whats should be inside the `fun2` , you should write generic `R` functions and use it in context of `shiny`, like so:

```
library(shiny)

fun1 <- function(x) {
    runif(x)
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
    hist(x)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    numericInput("n", "n", 50),
    plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
        fun1(input$n)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        fun2(randomVals())
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```